# Render component and close tag based on index map

Tags: html, reactjs

I have this code, how can I add a tag based on index ? I want to make a grid with 3 columns

```
<div>

    {items.map((row, i) => (
        {i % 3 === 0 && <div className={'grid-container'}>}
            <UniversityCard data={row} />
        {i % 3 === 2 && </div>}

    ))}
</div>
```

this code return `Parsing error: Unexpected token`

How can I show a tag based on index mod?

Update:

```
    {items.map((row, i) => (
        i % 3 === 0 ? <div className={'grid-container'}> : <>
            <UniversityCard data={row} />
        {i % 3 === 2 ? </div> : </>}
    ))}
</div>
```

The problem is within last `{i%3===2}` `it return expression expected`

Comment: You are already in map function. You don't need to use curly brackets inside map function. `=> ()` <-- remove these brackets and replace them with `{ }`. Then inside the function body, add a control structure and make sure to return the JSX

Comment: @Dilshan I've update my answer. it return `expression expected`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you need to loop an Array and create a structure something like below,

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

This is how I would do that. You cannot just return only closing tag in JSX. I have added two additional components, `<Row/>` and `<Col/>` just to make it clear to understand.

```
/**Credit for chunk method - https://github.com/30-seconds/30-seconds-of-code */
const chunk = (arr, size) =>
  Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) }, (v, i) =>
    arr.slice(i * size, i * size + size)
  );

const data = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

function UniversityCard(prop) {
  return <div>{prop.data}</div>;
}

function Row({ children }) {
  return <div className="my-row">{children}</div>;
}

function Col({ children }) {
  return <>{children}</>;
}

export default function App() {
  const chunked = chunk(data, 3);

  const renderColForRow = (data) => {
    return data.map((d) => {
      return (
        <Col>
          <UniversityCard data={d} />
        </Col>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {chunked.map((ch) => {
        return <Row>{renderColForRow(ch)}</Row>;
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Yes you have two loops and it may be not the best solution for loop a big array.

Or the easy way, maybe use bootstrap grid system. If you use bootstrap, In JavaScript you only need to do is,

```
data.map((row, i) => {
  return <div className="col-md-4"></div>
})
```

Comment: thanks. it worked!. still learning from the code.

i'm currently using Material-ui core grid system. that's the reason I can't use the className based

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry I don't have experience with meterial-ui grid. When I code in React, I use meterial ui for the ui components & bootstrap for the grid. By the way, you can add custom styles to your components. Meterial-UI have some hooks for that. `makeStyle` etc,